# How does Infura deal with Finality

Tags: go-ethereum, infura

When submitting smart contract calls to infura or subscribing to a contract's events, does infura have it's own finality bound or will I have to implement this in the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura is simply providing a JSON RPC / web3 gateway into the Ethereum network. So you'll have to interpret the (probabilistic) finality on your own.